# send function variable to external ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a modal that has a  element of text with an icon

```
<span class="edit-comment-icon" title="Edit"></span>
```

and when the icon is clicked it turns the h3 into a textarea:

```
$('.edit-comment-icon').click(function(){
var _this = $(this),
    h3Tag =_this.prev()[0],
    h3Value = productComment;

    var input = $('<textarea />', {
        val: h3Value, 
        type: "text", 
        class:'uk-width-4-10',
        style: 'padding: 5px',
        rows: '5'
        });

    h3Tag.replaceWith(input[0]);
    $('.edit-comment-icon').hide();
    $('.save-comment-button').removeClass('uk-hidden').css('font-size','20px');
})
```

The issue is I have an external ajax call that is using another set of data for submission, but I need to add into that data the value that is in this text area at the time they hit submit.

So if the header said "TEST" and they edit, and change it to "testing" in the textarea and hit save/submit, I need to pass "testing" to my ajax call along with the current data it's receiving:

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){
    $ajax({
      url: 'url',
      data: dataset /*but need to add textarea value to this*/
    });
})
```

How can I add the textarea value from this other function so that it is sent in the external ajax call?

Comment: can you change it in ajax success callback function?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm also confused on how to get the value from the textarea at time of save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a selector that targets the textarea element inside the modal element, for instance if your modal element had the class `my-modal` you could use `.my-modal textarea`

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){
    var value = $('.my-modal textarea').val();
    var dataset = {
      myTextarea:value
      //and/or other properties
    };    
    //or if dataset is already created
    dataset.myTextarea = value;

    $ajax({
      url: 'url',
      data: dataset
    });
})
```

If there are more than one textarea inside the modal you would need to add an id or some unique class to that textarea

```
var input = $('<textarea />', {
  val: h3Value, 
  type: "text", 
  class:'for-h3 uk-width-4-10',
  style: 'padding: 5px',
  rows: '5'
});
```

and then in the callback

```
var value = $('.my-modal .for-h3').val();
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, but I'll be able to try it shortly and let you know!